# How to change the window size while creating console process?

Tags: c++, winapi, process

I have a task, which includes me creating a console process. For changing size of the window I use a flag STARTF_USECOUNTCHARS and members .dwYCountChars and .dwXCountChars

```
    for (int i = 0; i < processes; i++)
    {
        stInfos[i].dwFlags = STARTF_USECOUNTCHARS;
        stInfos[i].dwYCountChars = 100;
        stInfos[i].dwXCountChars = 100;
        cmdline = path + args + L" " + std::to_wstring(i);
        if (CreateProcess(NULL, (LPWSTR)cmdline.c_str(), NULL, NULL, true, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE | NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, NULL, NULL, &stInfos[i], &prInfos[i]))
        {
        }
    }
```

The code changes only the width of the console to fit my monitor width, for example when i set the size to be 800x800 chars.
[The look of the console while setting it(the width is the size of my monitor)][1]

The height doesn't change and when setting the width smaller(500 chars for example) it still makes the window the width of the monitor.

The same happens when setting width smaller.

The flag STARTF_USESIZE and and members .dwYSize and .dwXSize don't work at all and the window creates with the same size as always

```
for (int i = 0; i < processes; i++)
    {
        stInfos[i].dwFlags = STARTF_USESIZE;
        stInfos[i].dwYSize = 5000;
        stInfos[i].dwXSize = 800;
        cmdline = path + args + L" " + std::to_wstring(i);
        if (CreateProcess(NULL, (LPWSTR)cmdline.c_str(), NULL, NULL, true, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE | NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, NULL, NULL, &stInfos[i], &prInfos[i]))
        {
        }
    }
```

How can you change it?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uD6Pk.png

Comment: 800x600 characters is *very* likely not going to fit on any monitor (unless you're choosing a tiny font and have very high display resolution). Are you confusing characters with pixels by chance?

Comment: Not sure about `dwXSize`,`dwYSize`. but  `dwXCountChars`, `dwYCountChars` is for defining the **buffer** size for the console and has nothing to do with the window size (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfoa).

Comment: @IInspectable that makes sense, but setting the character count less than usual(10 for example), the window doesnt shrink. Also the height doesn't change no matter what char count I set, neither bigger, nor less

Comment: @wohlstad then may I ask, do you know how is it possible to change the console window size, if it's possible?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know. But in general if you want to atract people to answer, I advise you to [edit] your question and provide a [mre]. The loop does not seem relevant, but all the details about the arguments you pass to `CreateProcess` are relevant but missing.

Comment: NT_CONSOLE_PROPS in a .lnk knows how so it has to be possible.

Comment: You could refer to the thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e7a7d96c-2d1c-4913-a6eb-fa0d1b9d48d1/createprocess-new-console-process-want-to-specify-window-size-in-character-cells?forum=vcgeneral
I suggest you could try to use [SetConsoleWindowInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolewindowinfo) to change the size of the console window.